# The property or field 'Id' has not been initialized

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, user-profile

I want to get user ID from client context by looping through groups. I wrote following code. When I run this code I get an exception

> "The property or field 'Id' has not been initialized. It has not been
>   requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be
>   explicitly requested."

```
using (ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext(siteURL))
            {
                //Use the following line if you wish to connect to sharepoint site using
                //a different credential than what the application is running under.
                //ctx.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                ctx.Credentials = cred;

                Web wsite = ctx.Web;
                ctx.Load(wsite, w => w.HasUniqueRoleAssignments, w => w.RoleAssignments.Include(roleAssigned => roleAssigned.Member.Title,
                        roleAssigned => roleAssigned.RoleDefinitionBindings.Include(
                        roleDef => roleDef.Name)));
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                ctx.Load(ctx.Web, web => web.Title);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();

                WebCollection websiteCollections = ctx.Web.Webs;
                ctx.Load(wsite);
                ctx.Load(websiteCollections);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                RoleAssignmentCollection rac = wsite.RoleAssignments;
                if (rac != null && rac.Count != 0)
                {
                    foreach (RoleAssignment ra in rac)
                    {
                        //Get only groups and skip users directly added to site
                        if (ra.Member.ToString() != "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.User")
                        {
                            foreach (RoleDefinition rd in ra.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                            {
                                //Skip groups which has Contribute or Read permission
                                if (!(rd.Name == "Contribute" || rd.Name == "Read"))
                                {
                                   int id=ra.Member.Id;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should load the `ra.Member` object once before accessing its properties.

Your code should look something like this inside the last if block.

```
    if (!(rd.Name == "Contribute" || rd.Name == "Read"))
    {
       ctx.Load(ra.Member); 
       ctx.ExecuteQuery();  
       int id = ra.Member.Id;
    }
```